# HANA concat rows

Tags: sql, concatenation, hana

I use SAP-HANA database. I have a simple 2 column table whose columns are number, name, noodles, fish . The rows are these:

```
number name noodles fish
1      tom    x     
1      tom           x
1      jack
2      jack  x
```

I would like to group the rows by the id, and concatenate the names into a field, and thus obtain this:

```
number  name   noodles   fish

1        tom     x        x
2       jack     x
```

Can you please tell me how we can perform this operation in sap-hana? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you did not really concatenate the names, but instead kept the same ones (if you would have concatenated the names as well, you would get something like jackjack in your result). I guess your x's indicate some sort of ABAP-style flags.

In any case, you would do this with grouping. This is a completely non-HANA thing (you can use the same basic SQL for any DB). You can group against several columns. All other columns that you want to select must be used in an aggregated expression (e.g. a SUM, MAX, COUNT, etc.).

To get the output from your question, I wrote the following code:

```
SELECT "ID", "NAME", MAX("FISH"), MAX("NOODLES") 
    FROM #TEST GROUP BY "ID", "NAME";
```

And got the same output as you. I used the MAX function based on the following assumption: you would want to get X if there is any X in the "concatenated" (aggregated) rows in that column. You get nothing / space if all the "concatenated" rows have space in them.